# Lua string.gsub with Multiple Patterns

Tags: string, lua, lua-patterns

I am working on renaming the Movie titles that has unwanted letters. The `string.gsub` can replace a string with "" nil value but I have around 200 string patterns that need to be replaces with "".

Right now I have to `string.gsub` for every pattern. I was thinking is there is a way to put all the string patterns in to single `string.gsub` line. I have searched around the web for the solution but still didn't got anything.

The movie title is like this `B.A.Pass 2013 Hindi 720p DvDRip CROPPED AAC x264 RickyKT`
and I want to remove the extra characters like `2013`, `Hindi`, `720p`, `DvDRip`, `CROPPED`, `AAC`, `x264`, `RickyKT`.

Comment: try this regex http://regex101.com/r/rR0eX0/2, see if it is worth a penny

Answer (score 11):

You can pass to `string.gsub` a table as the third argument like this:

```
local movie = "B.A.Pass 2013 Hindi 720p DvDRip CROPPED AAC x264 RickyKT"
movie = movie:gsub("%S+", {["2013"] = "", ["Hindi"] = "", ["720p"] = "", 
                       ["DvDRip"] = "", ["CROPPED"] = "", ["AAC"] = "", 
                       ["x264"] = "", ["RickyKT"] = ""})

print(movie)
```

Answer (score 1):

Put all of the patterns in a table and then enumerate the table, calling `string.gsub()` for each pattern:

```
str = "B.A.Pass 2013 Hindi 720p DvDRip CROPPED AAC x264 RickyKT"

patterns = {"pattern1", "pattern2", "pattern3"}
for i,v in ipairs(patterns) do
    str = string.gsub(str, v, "")
end
```

This will require many invocations of `string.gsub()`, but the code should be much more maintainable than having a lot of `string.gsub()` calls.

Comment: One possible problem is, a substring like `"722013p"` will be matched by `"2013"`, left with `"720p"`, then matched by `"720p"` which is not what's expected.

Answer (score 1):

To avoid to write keys and values on a table for every new entry, i'd write a function to handle a numerically indexed table (the patterns being the values).

This way I dont need to write `{["pattern_n"] = ""}` for every new pattern.

Ex:

```
PATTERNS = {"2013", "Hindi", "720p", "DvDRip", "CROPPED", "AAC", "x264", "RickyKT"}
function replace(match)
    local ret = nil
    for i, v in ipairs(PATTERNS) do
        if v:find(match) then
            ret = ""
        end
    end
    return ret
end


local movie = "B.A.Pass 2013 Hindi 720p DvDRip CROPPED AAC x264 RickyKT"
movie = movie:gsub("%S+", replace)

print(movie)
```

Answer (score 1):

You could do it in a simple function, that way you do not need to write the code each time per string, or just put `string.gsub`, and the replacement value for the string you need

**Function:**

```
local large_name = "B.A.Pass 2013 Hindi 720p DvDRip CROPPED AAC x264 RickyKT"

function clean_name(str)
  local v = string.gsub(str, "(.-)%s([%(%[']?%d%d%d?%d?[%)%]]?)%s*(.*)", "%1")
  return v
end

print(clean_name(large_name))
```

**Only string.gsub for value**

```
local large_name = "B.A.Pass 2013 Hindi 720p DvDRip CROPPED AAC x264 RickyKT"
local clean_name = string.gsub(large_name, "(.-)%s([%(%[']?%d%d%d?%d?[%)%]]?)%s*(.*)", "%1")

print(clean_name)
```

The replacement pattern places the first value (name of the movie) separated by a space and prints it, also identifies the year as the second value, to avoid error in the titles, so it is not necessary to place all the values ​​that can exist within the name of the movie and will avoid many false positives

**I add a testing function to test different movie names**

```
local testing = {"Whiplash 2014 [1080p]",
"Anon (2018) [WEBRip] [1080p] [YTS.AM]",
"Maze Runner The Death Cure 2018 [WEBRip] [1080p] [YTS.AM]",
"12 Strong [2018] [WEBRip] [1080p] [YTS.AM]",
"Kingsman The Secret Service (2014) [1080p]",
"The Equalizer [2014] [1080p]",
"Annihilation 2018 [WEBRip] [1080p] [YTS.AM]",
"The Shawshank Redemption '94",
"Assassin's Creed 2016 HC 720p HDRip 850 MB - iExTV",
"Captain Marvel (2019) [WEBRip] [1080p] [YTS.AM]",}

for k,v in pairs(testing) do
  local result = string.gsub(v, "(.-)%s([%(%[']?%d%d%d?%d?[%)%]]?)%s*(.*)", "%1")
  print(result)
end
```

**Output:**

> ```
> Whiplash
> Anon
> Maze Runner The Death Cure
> 12 Strong
> Kingsman The Secret Service
> The Equalizer
> Annihilation
> The Shawshank Redemption
> Assassin's Creed
> Captain Marvel
> ```