# Lua: string.gsub pattern(s) to permit multiple pattern replacement

Tags: lua, pattern-matching, gsub, lua-patterns

This topic has been partially handled before by another user in thread:
[Lua string.gsub with Multiple Patterns](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25280374/lua-string-gsub-with-multiple-patterns/33700374#33700374)

I'm having issues and I believe it is with my pattern (second) argument.  Here is my example of the `gsub` code I'm trying to use:

```
local dateCode = "MMM/dd-YYYY:ss"

--dateCode = dateCode:gsub(".*", {["%/"] = "s", ["%-"] = "n", ["%:"] = "c"}) --original code but removed after @Etan's comments.
dateCode = dateCode:gsub(".*", {["/"] = "s", ["-"] = "n", [":"] = "c"})

print(dateCode)

MMM/dd-YYYY:ss  --printed

MMMsddnYYYYcss  --desired
```

I believe that I shouldn't be looking over all characters like I currently have it, but I'm not sure what pattern I should be using for the `dateCode` variable.
The idea is to replace the keys with the first alpha character that it begins with.

Comment: What is your desired output here? `MMMsddnYYYYcss`? The keys in the `gsub` replacement need to equal the captured bits of the string that the pattern matches. You don't have `%` in your input so none of your keys can possibly match.

Comment: @EtanReisner you are correct.  That is the desired output.  I erroneously used the `%` as escape characters in my keys.  Thanks.  Once removed, still does not appear to provide the desired result.

Comment: Think about what you are matching with your pattern. What will the "result" of the match be? *That* is what `gsub` looks up in the table argument. So if you want to replace just those characters then you need to, individually, match *just* those characters.

Comment: @EtanReisner UGHH..... thank you for spelling it out of me.  `%p`......  I'll update my post to show the correct pattern.

Comment: Don't update the post. If you have a solution add an answer and accept it.

Comment: @EtanReisner much appreciate as always!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Since you want a select set of characters to be replaces, put them in a character set as the pattern:

```
dateCode = dateCode:gsub("[/:-]", {["/"] = "s", ["-"] = "n", [":"] = "c"})
```

What happens currently is, with the pattern `.*` in place, it matches the entire string. Since the string `"MMM/dd-YYYY:ss"` has no indexed value in the hash table (second argument), no replacement actually occurs.

Comment: Thanks hjpotter.  I used the following `dateCode:gsub("%p", {["/"] = "s", ["-"] = "n", [":"] = "c"})` and it worked.  What would be the consequences of doing it my way over the way you just posted?  Ahhh... I get your explanation!!!  Thank you.

Comment: `%p` covers a lot more characters. It'll also include characters such as `+`, `!` etc. While there'll be no effect on the performance (or output), I'd suggest using a harder limit in your `gsub` pattern. If you're sure about what you want, use specifically that.